# Merge two collections into the new one in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have two collections.

First (Normal Subscriptions) and a Second (Premium Subscriptions). They contain different fields, but they both have `Subscription_Type` filed and a `Name` field.

How can I make a **new** collection containing only these two fields?

**Normal Subscription schema**

```
  "NormalSubscription" : {

                "Some Other Data"  : {
                                        ....
                                     }
                "Name"             : String,
                "subscriptionType" : String,

        }
```

**Premium Subscription schema**

```
"PremiumSubscription" : {

            "Some Other Data"  : {
                                    ....
                                 }
            "Name"             : String,
            "subscriptionType" : String,

    }
```

**Collection I want to achieve**

```
    "SubscriptionList" : {
                "Name"             : String,
                "subscriptionType" : String     
    }
```

I have tried to obtain this with the use of [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). But without any success. Something in this manner:

```
db.SubscriptionList.aggregate
([
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "NormalSubscription",       
            let: "Name",   
            pipeline: "SubscriptionList", 
            as: "NormalSub"         
        }
    },

    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "PremiumSubscribtion", 
            let: "Name", 
            pipeline: "SubscriptionList",
            as: "PremiumSub"
        }
    }

])
```

Comment: `$lookup` purpose is to perform joins, which you are not willing to do. Have you considered executing 2 **find** queries?

Comment: I haven't considered find queries, but it seems to be a good idea.

Comment: Have you considered just entering something like the following for each collection? `SubscriptionList.insert_many(NormalSubscription.find({}, {'_id': 0, 'Name': 1, 'subscriptionType': 1}))` (PyMongo style) as per what Cider suggested.